# How to summarise variables separately which the variable name defined in vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Using below code to summarise variable according defined vector, but failed. Anyone can help on this ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
data('diamonds')
group_variables <- c('color','clarity','cut')
value_variables <- c('x','y','z')

for (group_variable in group_variables){
  for (value_variable in value_variables){
    result <- diamonds %>% 
      group_by(group_variable) %>% 
      summarise(values_sum=sum(value_variable))
     
    print(result)
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function `sym()` is ok ,the updated code as below. Just mark it.

```
for (group_variable in group_variables){
  for (value_variable in value_variables){
    group_variable <- sym(group_variable)
    value_variable <- sym(value_variable)
    result <- diamonds %>% 
      group_by({{group_variable}}) %>% 
      summarise(values_sum = sum({{value_variable}}))
    
    print(result)
  }  
}
```